# If the MAC adress is not in the database it adds it otherwise it ignores it and adds nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was just finishing developing my project and a problem came up, in the code below it was supposed that when a new device with a different MAC adress was connected and that MAC ADRESS was not in the database table it would insert in the Bi_dispositivo table with that new mac, but if the device is already with the MAC address registered in the table it would ignore it, but it doesn't work I am putting in a new MAC address and it just doesn't add someone can explain me what I did wrong in the procedure?

Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[dbo.Bi_DispositivoProced]



@disp_mac nvarchar(50),
@disp_nom nvarchar(50),
@ID_interno_cc Int
as
begin

declare @dispositivo INT = (select ID_interno_disp from Bi_dispositivo where disp_mac=@disp_mac)

if @dispositivo = null
begin
insert into Bi_dispositivo(disp_mac, disp_nom, ID_interno_cc)
values(@disp_mac,@disp_nom,@ID_interno_cc)
end

select ID_interno_disp 
from Bi_dispositivo 
where disp_mac=@disp_mac

end
```

Comment: It just doesn't add anything, but it doesn't give me any error in SQL... @Jaime Drq

Comment: … if @dispositivo = null ….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparison with `null` must be always performed with `is null` not with `= null`, because `null` is undetermined so it's equal to nothing.

```
if @dispositivo is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `if` at all?  Not only is it unneeded, but it introduces race conditions, so you could still get duplicate inserts.

One method uses `existing`:

```
insert into Bi_dispositivo (disp_mac, disp_nom, ID_interno_cc)
    select disp_mac, disp_nom, ID_interno_cc
    from (values (@disp_mac, @disp_nom, @ID_interno_cc)
         ) v(disp_mac, disp_nom, ID_interno_cc)
    where not exists (select 1 from Bi_dispositivo d where d.disp_mac = v.disp_mac);
```

A better method is to define a unique constraint on `disp_mac`:

```
alter table Bi_dispositivo add constraint unq_Bi_dispositivo_disp_mac
    unique (disp_mac);
```

Then just insert the row and catch or ignore an error if any:

```
begin try
    insert into Bi_dispositivo (disp_mac, disp_nom, ID_interno_cc)
        values (@disp_mac, @disp_nom, @ID_interno_cc);
end try
begin catch
end catch;
```

The database then ensures that `disp_mac` is unique, regardless of how the value is inserted or modified in the database.

Answer (score -1):

I would use `COUNT(*)`, set variable to count. If count is 0, insert into table.

Query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[dbo.Bi_DispositivoProced]

@disp_mac nvarchar(50),
@disp_nom nvarchar(50),
@ID_interno_cc Int
as
begin

declare @rowCount INT

select 
    COUNT(ID_interno_disp) = @rowCount 
from 
    Bi_dispositivo 
where 
    disp_mac = @disp_mac

if @rowCount = 0
begin
insert into Bi_dispositivo(disp_mac, disp_nom, ID_interno_cc)
values(@disp_mac,@disp_nom,@ID_interno_cc)
end

select ID_interno_disp 
from Bi_dispositivo 
where disp_mac=@disp_mac

end
```